# BUILD FAILED apache-tomcat-7.0.42-src build.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

I have both JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME set:

```
damechen@ubuntu:~/apache-tomcat-7.0.42-src$ echo $ANT_HOME 
/home/damechen/tmp/damechen/apache-ant-1.9.1
damechen@ubuntu:~/apache-tomcat-7.0.42-src$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0.25
damechen@ubuntu:~/apache-tomcat-7.0.42-src$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

I was trying to use ant to build tomcat, but it failed for some reasons related to build.xml.

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/damechen/apache-tomcat-7.0.42-src/build.xml:2396: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/damechen/apache-tomcat-7.0.42-src/build.xml:2625: Directory /usr/share/java/tomcat-native-1.1.27 creation was not successful for an unknown reason
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Mkdir.execute(Mkdir.java:70)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 0 seconds
damechen@ubuntu:~/apache-tomcat-7.0.42-src$
```

Anyone can kindly give me a hand? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As the exceptions says. The built failed while it was trying to create a directory by the name `tomcat-native-1.1.27` in `/usr/share/java/`.

Please give proper rights.

Comment: Thanks Junaid. It is the reason that the directory is not properly set in the build property file. I changed it, and the failure issue to this case is solved:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the build instructions for Apache tomcat:

- http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_42/BUILDING.txt

> (3.2) Building
>
> 1. The build is controlled by creating a ${tomcat.source}/build.properties
>      file.
>
>    It is recommended to always create the file, because of unfortunate
>      default value of base.path property. You may start with the following
>      content for the file:
>
>    ```
>    # ----- Default Base Path for Dependent Packages -----
>    # Replace this path with the directory path where dependencies binaries
>    # should be downloaded
>    base.path=/home/me/some-place-to-download-to
>    ```
> 2. Configure base.path property by adding it to the
>      ${tomcat.source}/build.properties file.
>
>    The base.path property specifies the place where Tomcat dependencies
>      required by the build are downloaded. It is recommended to place this
>      directory outside of the source tree, so that you do not waste your
>      time re-downloading the libraries.
>
>    - WARNING: The default value of base.path property makes the build script
>        to download libraries required to build Tomcat to the /usr/share/java
>        directory. On a typical Linux or MacOX system an ordinary user will not
>        have access to write to this directory. Even if you do have access to
>        that directory, it is likely not appropriate for you to write there.

Note the warning at the end.... This is the root cause of your issue.

## Analysis

The [build file](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_42/build.xml) is calling the "download-2" target when it fails:

```
  <target name="extras-commons-logging-prepare"
          depends="extras-prepare"
          description="Prepare to build web services extras package">

    <antcall target="downloadfile-2">
      <param name="sourcefile.1" value="${commons-logging-src.loc.1}"/>
      <param name="sourcefile.2" value="${commons-logging-src.loc.2}"/>
      <param name="destfile" value="${commons-logging-src.tar.gz}"/>
      <param name="destdir" value="${commons-logging.home}"/>
    </antcall>

    ..
    ..
```

In your build.properties file you have set the value of the **commons-logging.home** property to a directory path for which you do not have permissions to create a directory namely:

```
/usr/share/java/...
```

Digging further I see that [default properties](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_42/build.properties.default) file sets this path as follows:

```
# ----- Default Base Path for Dependent Packages -----
# Please note this path must be absolute, not relative,
# as it is referenced with different working directory
# contexts by the various build scripts.
base.path=/usr/share/java
#base.path=C:/path/to/the/repository
#base.path=/usr/local

..
..

commons-logging.version=1.1.1
commons-logging.home=${base.path}/commons-logging-${commons-logging.version}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! Please see my following comment as Answer below:)

Comment: @damingzi The answer you provided to your own question, was in fact a new question. I think that's why it was deleted by the moderator.